# Extract string within script tags from HTML

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to make a web scraper to get data from the following website (I would later like to do it for several airlines on the same website):
https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airlines/kl-klm/routes

I currently have the following code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

airlines = ['kl-klm']

for a in airlines:
    url = 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airlines/' + a + '/routes'
    page = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
    print(soup)
```

This gives me the source code for the whole page, but I would like to extract a specific chunk of text within script tags, which is

```
var arrRoutes=[{"airport1":{"country":"Denmark","iata":"AAL","icao":"EKYT","lat":57.092781,"lon":9.849164,"name":"Aalborg Airport"},"airport2":{"country":"Netherlands","iata":"AMS","icao":"EHAM","lat":52.308609,"lon":4.763889,"name":"Amsterdam Schiphol Airport"}},{"airport1":{"country":"United Kingdom","iata":"ABZ","icao":"EGPD","lat":57.201939,"lon":-2.19777,"name":"Aberdeen International Airport"},"airport2":{"country":"Netherlands","iata":"AMS","icao":"EHAM","lat":52.308609,"lon":4.763889,"name":"Amsterdam Schiphol Airport"}}...
```

...etc. all the way until the end of the list.

How can I extract this in such a way that I can find the total number of inbound and outbound flights for each airport? For example, the total number of times Amsterdam Schiphol Airport appears as airport 1 or 2?

Is there a way to first extract the string from the HTML and then convert it into a Python list with dictionaries? Or would it make more sense to just directly count each element in the string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extract data to python list using `ast.literal_eval`. I made a simple function `find_airport()`, where you supply data and airport name, and returns how many times it is in airport_1 and airport_2:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re
from ast import literal_eval
from pprint import pprint

airlines = ['kl-klm']

headers = {"Host":"www.flightradar24.com",
"Accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
"Accept-Encoding":"gzip,deflate,br",
"User-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.80 Safari/537.36"}

def find_aiport(data, name):
    airport_1, airport_2 = 0, 0
    for d in data:
        if d['airport1']['name'] == name:
            airport_1 += 1
        if d['airport2']['name'] == name:
            airport_2 += 1
    return airport_1, airport_2

for a in airlines:
    url = 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airlines/' + a + '/routes'
    page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')

    m = re.search(r'(?<=arrRoutes=)\[\{(.*?)\}\]', soup.text)
    l = literal_eval(m[0])
    pprint(l)

    print(find_aiport(l, 'Amsterdam Schiphol Airport'))
```

Prints:

```
[{'airport1': {'country': 'Denmark',
               'iata': 'AAL',
               'icao': 'EKYT',
               'lat': 57.092781,
               'lon': 9.849164,
               'name': 'Aalborg Airport'},
  'airport2': {'country': 'Netherlands',
               'iata': 'AMS',
               'icao': 'EHAM',
               'lat': 52.308609,
               'lon': 4.763889,
               'name': 'Amsterdam Schiphol Airport'}},
 {'airport1': {'country': 'United Kingdom',
               'iata': 'ABZ',
               'icao': 'EGPD',
               'lat': 57.201939,
               'lon': -2.19777,
               'name': 'Aberdeen International Airport'},
  'airport2': {'country': 'Netherlands',
               'iata': 'AMS',
               'icao': 'EHAM',
               'lat': 52.308609,
               'lon': 4.763889,
               'name': 'Amsterdam Schiphol Airport'}},

...and so on
```

And at the end:

```
(147, 146)
```

For "Amsterdam Schiphol Airport"

Comment: Fantastic, exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use `re.compile`

**Ex:**

```
import re

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
jData = soup.find("script", text=re.compile(r"var arrRoutes=.*?")).string
print( jData.replace("var arrRoutes=", ""))
```

**Output:**

```
[{"airport1":{"country":"Denmark","iata":"AAL","icao":"EKYT","lat":57.092781,"lon":9.849164,"name":"Aalborg Airport"},"airport2":{"country":"Netherlands","iata":"AMS","icao":"EHAM","lat":52.308609,"lon":4.763889,"name":"Amsterdam Schiphol Airport"}},{"airport1":{"country":"United Kingdom","iata":"ABZ","icao":"EGPD","lat":57.201939,"lon":-2.19777,"name":"Aberdeen International Airport"},"airport2":{"country":"Netherlands","iata":"AMS","icao":"EHAM","lat":52.308609,"lon":4.763889,"name":"Amsterdam Schiphol Airport"}},......
```